# 401 Error with AWS Cognito and correct access token

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito in my Spring boot application. I can successfuly register, verify and login with the user credentials, however when I try to access an endpoint that a user needs to be authenticated for, with the Bearer token from Cognito, I get a 401 error.

Security Config:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
             
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/v1/api/auth/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v1/api/auth/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v1/api/auth/verify-email").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v1/api/auth/verify-email/resend").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
}
```

Application.properties

```
spring.cloud.aws.security.cognito.app-client-id=XXX
spring.cloud.aws.security.cognito.region=eu-west-2
spring.cloud.aws.security.cognito.user-pool-id=eu-west-XXX

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.client-id=XXX
#spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.cognito.issuer-uri=https://cognito-idp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/eu-west-XXX
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=https://cognito-idp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/eu-west-XXXX
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the configuration on the API methods and the token validity and scopes?

Comment: I'm tryin to use it with my Rest API and I haven't added any methods in AWS, if you're reffering to that. The scope of the token is `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'`